# How to sort data in an array by date

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

I have an array of NSObjects called Messages. These objects have 4 different sub-variables. Their senders, messages, dates, and senderUIDs. Right now, I'm trying to sort the array by the dates that the messages come in

```
    var messages = [Message]()
```

That is the code for the array. Here is the code I have right now...

```
    messages.sort { $0.date > $1.date }
```

Since I'm using Firebase, it sorts the data alphabetically rather than chronologically, so when I take a snapshot, my messages array is all muddled up date wise.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Show the definiton of `Message`.

Comment: Are you currently using .childByAutoId when you write your messages to the database? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data
That would automatically order the messages because the generated ID is based on the timestamp.

Comment: Definition of message is 'class Message: NSObject {
    var sender: String!
    var senderUID: String!
    var message: String!
    var date: Date!
}'

Comment: I already have messages in child by auto id

Comment: Jen Person - You're right... I'm usign childByAutoId, yet I'm still getting results out of chronological order, even though I checked Firebase, and as I send more messages, it is ordered chronologically

Comment: the sort function is from Swift's standard library and will sort the array stored in var messages. what does it have with Firebase?

Comment: Store your dates in a time stamp format. For example 20170524191100